# How to set title for org-alert for notification?

Tags: org-mode, notifications

I use [org-alert](https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert) to send notifications about my agenda to `libnotify`, so I can see the notifications via `Dunst`.  All works well but everytime the notification pops up, its title is pretty generic.  I have Todo in multiple org files, so I am trying to differentiate between them, i.e. Work todo, Home todo....etc.

Digging into the `org-alert.el`, this line seems to change the title:

```
(defvar org-alert-notification-title "*org*" "Title to be sent with notify-send.")
```

You can see the default action is to set the title as ***org**.  How do I set it to be the name of the buffer where I have the notified Todo list? I tried:

```
(defvar org-alert-notification-title (current-buffer) )
```

with no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It cannot be done statically (i.e. with just a `defvar`): it needs to be done dynamically, i.e. when the notification is generated.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the current version of [`org-alert`](https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert), I think the best way to do it is to redefine the `org-alert--dispatch` function so that the title is dynamically generated by calling a function to calculate it, instead of using the value of a variable:

```el
(defvar org-alert-notification-title-function nil)

(defun org-alert-notification-title ()
  "If `org-alert-notification-title-function' is defined and is a function, call it
and return what it returns; otherwise return the value of the variable `org-alert-notification-title'"
  (cond ((null org-alert-notification-title-function) org-alert-notification-title)
        ((not (functionp org-alert-notification-title-function)) org-alert-notification-title)
        (t (funcall org-alert-notification-title-function))))

(defun org-alert--dispatch ()
  (let* ((entry (org-alert--parse-entry))
     (head (car entry))
     (time (cadr entry)))
    (when (org-alert--check-time time)
      (alert (concat time ": " head) :title (org-alert-notification-title)))))
```

All of these would be changes to `org-alert.el` (IOW, you are forking `org-alert.el`: if this works for you, I might submit the changes as a PR to the github site): the first two definitions are additions to the file, but the third is a *replacement*
The above does not change the current behavior: it redefines `org-alert--dispatch` to call a function `org-alert-notification-title` (instead of using the variable of the same name directly - btw, emacs lisp allows the same name to be used for a variable *and* a function: if the name appears in a function context, the function value is used, otherwise the variable value is used).

When that function is called, it checks a (new) variable `org-alert-notification-title-function`: if that variable is nil or is not a function, then the value of the variable `org-alert-notification-title` is returned, which reproduces the current behavior. But if you redefine `org-alert-notification-title-function` to have a function that returns  a string as its value, the function is called and the returned string is the return value of the call to the `org-notification-title` function. The point is that the function is called when the notification is needed, so it can take advantage of its context to return information of interest (like the file name of the buffer in which it is evaluated: it just so happens that it is evaluated in exactly the buffer of the file that contains the entry that gives rise to the notification - phew!)

So you can customize the behavior by defining your own function and setting it as the value of the variable `org-alert-notification-title-function` in your init file:

```el
(defun ndk/org-alert-notification-title ()
  (concat "*ORG* " (let ((fn (buffer-file-name))) (if fn (file-name-base fn) "no file?"))))

(setq org-alert-notification-title-function #'ndk/org-alert-notification-title)
```

BTW, there is a bug in `org-alert.el`: it only recognizes `DEADLINE` or `SCHEDULED` timestamps - it does not recognize plain timestamps. See this [Important](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling) note in the manual for why this is a serious omission.

In addition, `org-alert`'s error handling is not particularly robust: if `org-alert--parse-entry` does not recognize a time, then a `nil` is passed to `org-alert-check--time` and the latter keels over and dies.